# Extract Unique links in a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract Unique links in this webpage. My codes run very smoothly. However, the result is incorrect. Somehow the codes doesn't extract enough links in the webpage. It should be 117 unique links but the codes return only 90 unique links. Can somebody help check what the problem is with my codes? Thanks !

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

tags= soup.find_all('a', {"href": True})
b = {tag.get('href') for tag in tags}
for c in b:
  print(c)
```

Comment: Your code returns `119` at my side.

Comment: some results just contain things like " #content " or " /en.html " . I don't understand why they are considered hyperlinks in the results. They aren't even started with "http"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work on my end. Maybe try selecting the links differently like here:

```py
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    links = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href^="http"]')]
    unique_links = set(links)
    print(len(links))
    print(len(unique_links))
```

output:

```
219
90
```

Comment: Thanks. So there are some lines like "#content" or "/en.html" which shouldn't be counted as hyperlinks in my opinion. if I copy and paste the results into Excel and filter out those that don't begin with http, then the results are only 90 lines.

Comment: then change the selector into `soup.select('a[href^="http"]')` which will give you the URLs that start with `http` (and `https` etc). Unique links drop to 90 in that case

Comment: Thanks Abdusco. I just don't understand why those that don't begin with http are also considered href in python. I just want the links, and I thought all the links are started with http.

Comment: href is an attribute of `<a>` link elements. Href of a link can be set to a relative url (i.e. begin with `/some/part/of/a/website`) or absolute (`http://example.com/some/part/of/a/website`) or refer to another part of the website (i.e. `#heading1`) or do nothing at all (i.e. `#`)

Comment: Ok now I got it. Thanks a lot Abdusco !